# If time after specified add another day to delivery php

Tags: php, date, time

The thing I am trying to accomplish is we delivery every Tuesday & Thursday and i would like to limit if the order is placed on Monday after 5pm then they have to wait till Friday. And if the order on Thursday after 5pm they have to wait till Tuesday.

```
function freeDelivery($date){
    $holidays = array("05/30/2012","07/04/2012","09/05/2012","11/24/2012","11/25/2012","12/25/2012","12/31/2012","01/01/2013","05/28/2013","07/04/2013","09/03/2013","11/22/2013","11/23/2013","12/25/2013");
    $checkday = strtotime($date);
    // check if it's a holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }

    //sun
    if (date("w",$checkday) == 0) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +2 day");
    }
    //mon
    elseif (date("w",$checkday) == 1) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 days");
    }
    //tue
    elseif(date("w",$checkday) == 2) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +2 days");
    }
    //wen
    elseif (date("w",$checkday) == 3) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 days");
    }
    //thur
    elseif (date("w",$checkday) == 4) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +5 days");
    }
    //fri
    elseif (date("w",$checkday) == 5) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +4 days");
    }
    //sat
    elseif (date("w",$checkday) == 6) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +3 days");
    }

    // make sure it's not another holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }
    return $checkday;
}
```

The code above is use to determinate the shipping date depending on the date during the week.

Thank you any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you echo the script Storm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you meant after 5p on Monday is **Thursday**, and then after 5p on **Wednesday** you meant Tuesday...try the following:

**edit** 
easiest way would be to just add your code back into the function.

```
function freeDelivery($date){
    $holidays = array("05/30/2012","07/04/2012","09/05/2012","11/24/2012","11/25/2012","12/25/2012","12/31/2012","01/01/2013","05/28/2013","07/04/2013","09/03/2013","11/22/2013","11/23/2013","12/25/2013");
    $checkday = strtotime($date);
    // check if it's a holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }

    $thedate = date("m/d/Y",$checkday);
    $dayofweek = date("w",$checkday);
    $dayincrease = array(0 => 2, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 1, 4 => 5, 5 => 4, 6 => 3);
    $after5 = (date("G",$checkday) >= 17);

    $increase = "";
    if($after5 && $dayofweek == 1) {
        // monday after 5p = thurs
        $increase = "+3 days";
    } elseif($after5 && $dayofweek == 3) {
        // wednesday after 5p = tues
        $increase = "+6 days";
    } else {
        $increase = "+" . $dayincrease[$dayofweek] . " days";
    }
    $checkday = strtotime($thedate." ".$increase);

    // make sure it's not another holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }
    return $checkday;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the miss type this works perfectly thank you just a quick question how would i be able to add my array with the holiday into this. Thank you again.

Comment: How would you return this as an ECHO? <?php echo $checkday?

Comment: @bybe Yes, change `return $checkday;` with `echo $checkday;` or assign the function call to a variable and then echo it - `$var = freeDelivery($date); echo $var;`